# Limit User To Run Specific Commands

Tags: bash, security, bashrc, non-root-user, restricted-shell

I have a user `test1` that i want to limit it to only run specific commands. I found [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65822) solution and I tested it (logged in with test1 and ran some random commands. none of them worked but `date`) and it worked. here is what i did:

```
cp /bin/bash /bin/rbash
useradd -s /bin/rbash test1
mkdir /home/test1/bin
chmod 755 /home/test1/bin
echo "PATH=$HOME/bin" >> /home/test1/.bashrc
echo "export PATH" >> /home/test1/.bashrc
chattr +i /home/test1/.bash_profile
ln -s /usr/bin/date /home/test1/bin
```

since I'm more of a DBA than a linux pro like you guys I don't know if this is enough and if there is any other thing i need to do to prevent this `test1` from doing anything on system.any suggestion for increasing security?

as you can see, if i create link for a command like `ifconfig`:

```
ln -s /sbin/ifconfig /home/test1/bin
```

this user `test1` can also run `add | del | up | down` with `ifconfig`. how i can limit this command with for example this option `-a` or it can be executed with no options at all?

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary users aren't permitted to change network interfaces.

e.g. my non-root user can view interface details with `ifconfig`:

```
$ ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 178399193  bytes 213874320365 (199.1 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 50539358  bytes 36748192570 (34.2 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xba200000-ba21ffff
```

but can't take the interface down:

```
$ ifconfig eth0 down
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
```

In short, don't let them run `ifconfig` as root (e.g. with `sudo`) and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: what about other commands like ifconfig that have options?

Comment: they too will be restricted by the permissions on whatever file or device node or kernel parameter they are trying to change.   e.g. as a normal user who is NOT in the `disk` group, I can't run even `fdisk -l /dev/sda`, let alone change the partition table - because the perms on /dev/sda don't allow me to.

Comment: btw, you probably want to make `.bashrc` immutable as well as `.bash_profile`

Comment: great point! ( since there are really important databases on these machines i'm REALLY worried about those who want to use this user. there are always unexpected exceptions that cause serious problems)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running `/bin/rm`? And did you read the warning at the top of the article?

> Disclaimer : This is just a hack, not recommended for Actual Production Use

I would also read the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21649384/96588) to a duplicate on Stack Overflow.

If you want to actually restrict a user *securely* you probably need to look into a permissions framework like SELinux or AppArmor.

Comment: The accepted answer in that SO link is a terrible way to use `rbash` - it allows the restricted user to run any program except those that are blacklisted with aliases **instead** of setting the PATH to a directory containing only copies/links of whitelisted programs (incl. restricted editors, if an editor is needed, like `rvim` or `rnano`).    BTW, even without apparmor or selinux,  rbash is not easy to break out of, especially if there's only a small number of whitelisted programs that can be run. The whitelisting answer by Victor Wong is better (and is the method being used by the OP).